# How to auto-fill and display data in Django from fields of User model to another model from a different app?

Tags: django, view, model

I'm new in Django and right now I'm working to a payment application project for registered users and for non-registered users. My User model has some required fields from the paper invoice like below:

```
#users/models.py
class User(AbstractBaseUser):
   email = models.EmailField(max_length=255, unique=True)
   name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False, null=False)
   phone = models.CharField(max_length=11, blank=False, null=False)
   clientid = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=False, unique=True)
```

Notice that the authentication process is based on e-mail address and the required field from the invoice payment is "clientid, phone, name". The other app called payments has 1 model class for non-registered users and for authenticated users like below:

```
#payments/models.py
class Payment(models.Model):
    invoiceid = models.IntegerField(blank=False, null=False)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=False, null=False)
    amount = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=20)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=255, blank=False, null=False)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=11, blank=False, null=False)
    clientid = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=False, unique=False)
```

For both models I'm using crispy forms, for non-registered users is quite easy to make the payment if they fill all the fields. (different templates are used for this actions).
What I want to achieve is when the user is registered and wants to make a payment, the fields like "name, phone and clientid should be filled automatically and displayed to the user in read mode only based on the registration user table. What kind of relation should I use? ForeignKey or something different? 
The forms.py file from payments app look like this for a non-registered user:

```
#payments/forms.py
class PaymentRegister(forms.ModelForm):
    invoiceid = forms.IntegerField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={"placeholder":"Invoice number"}))
    name = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={"placeholder":"Name from the invoice"})
    clientid = forms.IntegerField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={"placeholder":"Clientid from the invoice"}))
    amount = forms.DecimalField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={"placeholder":"Total amount to pay"}))
    email = forms.EmailField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={"placeholder":"example@email.com"}))
    phone = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={"placeholder":"Phone number"}))

    class Meta:
        model = PaymentRegister
        fields = ['invoiceid', 'name', 'clientid', 'amount', 'email', 'phone']

    def save(self, commit=True):
        payment = super(PaymentRegister, self).save(commit=False)
        payment.invoiceid = self.cleaned_data['invoiceid']
        payment.name = self.cleaned_data['cumparator']
        payment.clientid = self.cleaned_data['clientid']
        payment.amount = self.cleaned_data['suma']
        payment.email = self.cleaned_data['email']
        payment.phone = self.cleaned_data['telefon']
        if commit:
            payment.save()
        return payment
```

There is my view to register a Payment:

```
#payments/views.py
def payment_register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = PaymentRegister(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            amount = form.cleaned_data.get('amount')
            invoiceid = form.cleaned_data.get('invoiceid')
            email = form.cleaned_data.get('email')
            return redirect('success')
    else:
        form = PaymentRegister()
return render(request, 'payments/payment.html', {'form':form})
```

I need to make a new model for registered users to make the payment and if the answer is Yes how can I connect the fields "clientid, phone, name" from User model to register and display them in Invoice model? 
Right now my PaymentRegister model looks the same for non-registered users and for registered users which is quite redundant.

Thanks for the support!

Comment: Get the auth user from setting as you hav created a custom user and get it as a foreign key

Comment: The clientid from User model is not a primary key in the table so is quite hard to link this field for PaymentRegistration model. What should I do? Maybe signals can be a good a idea? Thanks

Comment: can i get a good scenario of what your are trying to achieve here cause you say you want clientid, phone from user model but those fields are in payementRegister model. If you want to access those fields than you gotta relate that model to where you want it.

Answer (score 0):

Import the get user model from setting.py

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
```

Get the user as foreignkey

```
User= models.ForeignKey(get_user_model(),on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Comment: Which file I need to modify to get the User model as a ForeignKey? Because what I need to register is the PaymentRegister model with data from User model. Thanks

Comment: Add that user field in your payment model that way you can access all the user fields

Comment: And how to assign clientid from User to PaymentRegister after adding the user field in payment model? Like this? 
`class PaymentRegister(models.Model):
    User = models.ForeignKey(get_user_model(), on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    clientid = models.ForeignKey('User.clientid', on_delete=models.CASCADE)`